# perl asn1 module encode SEQUENCE OF SEQUENCE

Tags: perl, encoding, sequence, asn.1

In the exmaple below, the asn1 definition has two tags schoolId and student. The tag student is SEQUENCE of SEQUENCE. I get the student info from a a file in JSON format such as:

{"school1": [{"name": "jason","id": 12345, "age": 14}, {"name": "karen","id": 12346, "age": 14},{"name": "mike","id": 12347, "age": 15}]}

{"school2": [{"name": "dave","id": 12645, "age": 16}, {"name": "angel","id": 12346, "age": 14},{"name": "susan","id": 12347, "age": 15}]}

So each school has a different number of students. My question is how to encode the student tag since it has unspecified number of students.
Thanks for your help!

```
use Convert::ASN1;
use Data::Dumper;

my %scope = qw(base  0 one    1 single 1 sub    2 subtree 2);
my %deref = qw(never 0 search 1 find   2 always 3);

my $search_pdu = Convert::ASN1->new;
$search_pdu->prepare(q(
  SEQUENCE {
    schoolId     INTEGER,
    student [0]  SEQUENCE OF SEQUENCE {
      name       STRING,
      id         INTEGER,
      age        INTEGER
    }
  }
)) or die $search_pdu->error;

$buf = $search_pdu->encode(
  schoolId => 1001,
  student   => [
    {
      name  => "Jason Howard",
      id    => 310089,
      age   => 14
    },
    {
     name  => " Angel Disante",
     id    => 310456,
     age   => 15
    }
  ]
);

$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
print Dumper( $search_pdu->decode($buf));

$h = unpack("H*",$buf);
print $h,"\n";
```

My question, For example, if school1 has 100 students, school2 has 300 students, ......., is there any way to use a for loop in the encode function to figure out the number of students programmatically?

```
 $student_json = "{"school-1001": [{"name": "jason","id": 12345, "age": 14}, {"name": "karen","id": 12346, "age": 14},{"name": "mike","id": 12347, "age": 15}]}";

student  => [
    for my $hashref (@{$student_json}) {
    {
         name => $hashref->{'name'},
         id  => $hashref->{'id'},
         age  => $hashref->{'age'}                                    
    }
]
```

I tried many ways to use the for loop as shown above to encode programmatically, but it always failed.

Comment: What errors do you get? For me it seems like the encoding works fine with variable number of students, but I am not familiar with ASN.1 encoding so I am probably missing something

Answer (score 0):

Given a JSON string with the school and student data, you can try:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Convert::ASN1;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON::XS;

my $json = <<'END'; 
{
  "school1": [{"name": "jason","id": 12345, "age": 14}, {"name": "karen","id": 12346, "age": 14},{"name": "mike","id": 12347, "age": 15}],
  "school2": [{"name": "dave","id": 12645, "age": 16}, {"name": "angel","id": 12346, "age": 14},{"name": "susan","id": 12347, "age": 15}]
}
END

my $hash = decode_json $json;

my $search_pdu = Convert::ASN1->new;
$search_pdu->prepare(q(
  school SEQUENCE OF SEQUENCE {
    schoolId     INTEGER,
    student      SEQUENCE OF SEQUENCE {
      name       STRING,
      id         INTEGER,
      age        INTEGER
   }
}
)) or die $search_pdu->error;

my @schools;
my $data = {school => \@schools};
my $school_id = 1001;
for my $school ( keys %$hash ) {
    my @students;
    my $item = { schoolId => $school_id, student => \@students };
    for my $student (@{$hash->{$school}}) {
        push @students, $student;
    }
    push @schools, $item;
    $school_id++;
} 

my $buf = $search_pdu->encode( $data );

$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
print Dumper( $search_pdu->decode($buf));
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'school' => [
    {
      'student' => [
        {
          'name' => 'jason',
          'id' => 12345,
          'age' => 14
        },
        {
          'name' => 'karen',
          'id' => 12346,
          'age' => 14
        },
        {
          'age' => 15,
          'id' => 12347,
          'name' => 'mike'
        }
      ],
      'schoolId' => 1001
    },
    {
      'schoolId' => 1002,
      'student' => [
        {
          'age' => 16,
          'id' => 12645,
          'name' => 'dave'
        },
        {
          'name' => 'angel',
          'age' => 14,
          'id' => 12346
        },
        {
          'name' => 'susan',
          'age' => 15,
          'id' => 12347
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Hello Håkon, thanks a lot of your input. Please see my comments below.

Comment: Yes I guess so, you mean: Given a JSON file with schools, determine what should be the argument to `encode()`  programmatically?

Comment: Hi Håkon, I tried many ways to use a for loop to encode programmatically, but always failed. Can you please take a look at the my code below to see what I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: So you have one `$student_json` variable for each school? What about the school id?

Comment: Yes, one $student_json variable for each school. I don't worry about school id at this moment. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Håkon. Will try and let you know.

Comment: Hi Håkon, it works great. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My question, For example, if school1 has 100 students, school2 has 300 students, ......., is there any way to use a for loop in the encode function to figure out the number of students programmatically?

```
 $student_json = "{"student": [{"name": "jason","id": 12345, "age": 14}, {"name": "karen","id": 12346, "age": 14},{"name": "mike","id": 12347, "age": 15}]}";

student  => [
    for my $hashref (@{$student_json}) {
    {
         name => $hashref->{'name'},
         id  => $hashref->{'id'},
         age  => $hashref->{'age'}                                    
    }
]
```

Comment: Please don't use "answers" to post follow-up questions. Move this code to your "question"  by pressing the "edit" button below you question. Then delete this post.